# Why isn't SVN respecting my svn:ignore file?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I'm using Mac 10.9.5 and SVN 1.7.9 (r1462340).  On my termianl I enter

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

Within this file, I have a line that reads

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
```

However, when I execute "svn status" from the command line, it lists files like so ...

```
?       src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar
```

This file occurs in a direcotry I'd like to ignore.  What is the right way to get SVN to ignore all file within this directory?

Comment: Is 'lib' already versioned by your repository?

Comment: It was.  I removed it, however, still "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib" and "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes" are showing when I run "svn status".  Both of tehse directories I listed in my svn ignore directives, above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

svn:ignore only applies to the immediate directory. You will need to put "lib" in the property for the WEB-INF directory.